# Vue countdown is not working on IOS browsers

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**Countdown made in Vue using Laravel**

Hi I created a countdown in Vue.js and Laravel and it works perfectly in all the browsers but not on IOS browsers.

Here you can see my code:

**Vue component on blade file**

```
<countdown-button
          until="{{ $active->ends_at }}"
          url='{{ route('dashboard.active.show', $active->uuid) }}' />
```

As you can see, it is a normal component using props, and I must use without ":" because if I add it, I get an error and it says it must be a number instance of String, when using with props.

Here is my Vue.js component

```
<template>
    <div class="countdown__container">
        <div v-if="finished">{{ endsAt }}</div>

        <div v-else class="countdown__date--container">
            <div class="countdown__date--item2">
                <span>{{ remaining.days }} days</span>
                <span>{{ remaining.hours }} hours </span>
                <span>{{ remaining.minutes }} minutes </span>
                <span>{{ remaining.seconds }} seconds </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div :show="butt" class="lower-box">
            <a :href="url" class="theme-btn style-one">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>PLAY NOW
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import moment from 'moment';

    export default {
        props: {
            url: String,
            until: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            endsAt: { default: 'Game finished!' },

        },
        data () {
            return {
                now: new Date(),
                butt: true,
            };
        },
        created () {
            this.refreshEverySecond();
        },
        computed: {

            finished () {
                return this.remaining.total <= 0;
            },
            remaining () {

                let remaining = moment.duration(Date.parse(this.until) - this.now);

                if (remaining <= 0) this.$emit('finished');

                return {
                    total: remaining,
                    years: this.pad(remaining.years(),2),
                    months: this.pad(remaining.months(),2),
                    days: this.pad(remaining.days(),2),
                    hours: this.pad(remaining.hours(),2),
                    minutes: this.pad(remaining.minutes(),2),
                    seconds: this.pad(remaining.seconds(),2)
                };
            }
        },
        methods: {

            pad(num, size) {
                var s = "000000000" + num;
                return s.substr(s.length-size);
            },
            refreshEverySecond () {
                let interval = setInterval(() => this.now = new Date(), 1000);
                this.$on('finished', () => {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    this.butt = false;
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
   .countdown__date--item2 {
       font-size: 16px;
       color: orange;
       font-weight: bold;
   }
</style>
```

this component just gets two props, they are url and endsAt.
It only shows a countdown.

It works 100% on desktop browsers and with andriod

[image]

But on IOS browser it shows this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use moment `diff()` in computed `remaining`:

```js
remaining () {

  let until = moment().from(this.until);
  let now = moment().from(this.now);

  let remaining = moment().duration(until.diff(now));

  if (remaining <= 0) this.$emit('finished');

  return {
    total: remaining,
    years: this.pad(remaining.years(),2),
    months: this.pad(remaining.months(),2),
    days: this.pad(remaining.days(),2),
    hours: this.pad(remaining.hours(),2),
    minutes: this.pad(remaining.minutes(),2),
    seconds: this.pad(remaining.seconds(),2)
  };
}
```

Comment: My mistake: use `moment().from(...)`. I updated sample code.

Comment: I updated with your code and I got that error. It's for moment object, I think